# Oracle query optimization on 100 million table

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the SMAPLE query. How can I write this optimally?? It is scanning around 80 million records.. It runs hours together without any results

select * FROM (SELECT organization, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empno, sal ORDER BY deptno DESC) AS row_num
FROM  emp) x
Where
x.row_num=1
And
x.organization !=3

Beloe are all I tried, which didn’t help at all..

UNIQUE Index on deptno

COMPOSITE INDEX ON (empno, sal)

Additional NON-UNIQUE index on Organization column

I tried re-writing the inequality condition as x.organization< 3 or x.organization > 3 with no luck

Nothing is helping to produce results.. they query just runs for hours with NO RESULTS

please advice

Comment: Please get the explain plan and see what the optimizer is up to. Do this after gathering stats on all the tables

Comment: select count(1) from emp and select count(1) from emp where organization != 3, what are their result?

Comment: You are filtering on organization in the outer block without it being included in the inner SQL. I realise you are trying to anonymize your SQL but you are also removing any context about data distribution, how many rows per partition key...

Comment: This query does not work because of `x.organization !=3` - you didn't select column `organization` in subquery.

Comment: your right sorry I missed.. this is made-up query, as i cannot paste my original query for compliance purpose.. correct query below.. Is there any way we can rewrite this, to avoid full table scan?? 
select * FROM (SELECT organization, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empno, sal ORDER BY deptno DESC) AS row_num
FROM  emp) x
Where
x.row_num=1
And
x.organization !=3 there are around 60 Million per partiton key

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT empname,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY empno, sal ORDER BY deptno DESC) AS row_num
      FROM  emp
     ) x
Where x.row_num = 1;
```

the optimal index is `emp(empno, sal, deptno desc)`.

It might be faster to try a correlated subquery:

```
select e.*
from emp e
where e.deptno = (select max(e2.deptno) from emp e2 where e2.empno = e.empno and e2.sal = e.sal);
```

Comment: Perhaps getting the explain plan for both may help - after gathering the stats

Comment: index is emp(empno, sal, deptno desc)-- this one created a functional based index and no luck still full table scan and same cost.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a composite index on  `empno, sal deptno`.

This will speed things up as the ordering will be done and the DB will not have to do the sorting

But I can be wrong - The explain plan will help